# Union of two cycle graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked to find the union of two cycle graph.

Union of $C_3$ and $C_5$ and union of $C_4$ and $C_4$.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to find it?

Does union of $C_4$ and $C_4$ actually mean combining the two square together such as that it is a new graph with 6 vertics and 6 edges?

And what about union of $C_3$ and $C_5$?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, union of graphs means *disjoint union*, where for graphs $G_1 = (V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V_2,E_2)$, $G_1 \cup G_2 = (V_1 \cup V_2, E_1 \cup E_2)$ without considering whether graphs have some mutual nodes/edges or not. This means $C_4 \cup C_4$ is simply a disconnected graph with two $C_4$ components. So it has $8$ vertices and $8$ edges.

If it is not used in the meaning of disjoint union, then the result depends on vertex and edge set of the graphs. However, the definition $G_1 \cup G_2 = (V_1 \cup V_2, E_1 \cup E_2)$ remains the same.

---

**EDIT FOR AN EXAMPLE:** Take $G_1 = (V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V_2,E_2)$ where $G_1 \cong G_2 \cong C_4$ ($\cong$ states that they are isomorphic to $C_4$, I used that because I will enumerate vertices of $C_4$'s differently) where $$V_1 = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}, E_1 = \{v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_4v_1\}$$ and $$V_2 = \{v_1,v_2,v_5,v_6\}, E_2 = \{v_1v_2,v_2v_5,v_5v_6,v_6v_1\}$$
Then, 
$G_1 \cup G_2 = (V_1 \cup V_2, E_1 \cup E_2)$ is the following graph:

[image]

---

So in your question, since it is not specified, I assumed it is disjoint union. If that is not the case, let me know so that I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then is it correct if i say union of $C_3$ and $C_5$ is two disconnected graph as well?

Comment: Yes, it is a disconnected graph with two components, one of which is $C_3$ and other is $C_5$. If you want, I can give an example for the case where it is not disjoint union by editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Is it possible to give me an example??

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example for the case where union is not disjoint.